# NetSuite FreeMarker Advanced PDF HTML Template IF ELSE Error

Tags: netsuite, freemarker

I have the following NetSuite Advanced PDF HTML Template code that is giving me an error:

```
<#if record.item?has_content>

<table class="itemtable" style="width: 100%;"><!-- start items --><#list record.item as item><#if item_index==0>
<thead>
  <tr>
  <th colspan="4">Item Code</th>
  <th colspan="12">Item Description</th>
  <th align="right" colspan="2">UOM1</th>
  <th align="right" colspan="3">${item.quantity@label}</th>
  <th align="right" colspan="3">UOM2</th>
  <th align="right" colspan="4">Unit Price (excl. VAT)</th>
  <th align="right" colspan="3">${item.amount@label}</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
</#if><tr>
  <td colspan="4">${item.item}</td>
  <td colspan="12">${item.description}</td>
  <td align="right" colspan="2">${item.custcolsyn_uom}&nbsp;${item.custcolsyn_unit_measure}</td>
  <td align="right" colspan="3">${item.quantity}</td>
  <td align="right" colspan="3">${item.units}</td>
  <td align="right" colspan="4"><#if item.rate?has_content>${item.rate?keep_before_last(".")}.${item.rate?keep_after_last(".")[0..1]}<#else>&nbsp;</#if></td>
  <td align="right" colspan="3">${item.amount}</td>
  </tr>
  </#list><!-- end items --></table>
</#if>
```

The problem lies with the line:

```
<td align="right" colspan="4"><#if item.rate?has_content>${item.rate?keep_before_last(".")}.${item.rate?keep_after_last(".")[0..1]}<#else>&nbsp;</#if></td>
```

It looks like FreeMarker is evaluating the following part

```
${item.rate?keep_before_last(".")}.${item.rate?keep_after_last(".")[0..1]}
```

even when the line item does not have anything for the rate. Surely

```
<#if item.rate?has_content>
```

should prevent that evaluation from happening. I was trying to only keep 2 decimals worth of currency data and all other methods I tried lost the currency symbol.

We are on the latest version of NetSuite (2018.2).

The error message is:

```
The template cannot be printed due to the following errors: 

Error on line 239, column 95 in template.

Detail...

Range start index 0 is out of bounds, because the sliced string has only 0 character(s). (Note that indices are 0-based).
The blamed expression:
==> 0..1 [in template "template" at line 239, column 128]

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
- Failed at: ${item.rate?keep_after_last(".")[0..1]} [in template "template" at line 239, column 95]
----


Please contact your administrator.
```

Anybody have any ideas of what I'm doing wrong or how I can fix this?

Comment: If rate start with `.` you can get this exception

Comment: Rate is null/empty/blank

Comment: Is `item.rate` a number or a string? Try: `${item.rate?is_number?c`. (Or if NetSuite was forked form some ancient FM version, and so doesn't know `?c`, then use `?string` instead of the `?c`)

Comment: `${item.rate?is_number?c}` returns true, even though there is obviously a currency symbol of R in front of the number.

Comment: Yet if you just write `${1}`, it doesn't have the `R`? So then, I guess `${item.rate?string('#.00')}` loses the `R` as well, and also `${item.rate + 1}`. Does it? I just wonder how they implemented this. It's doable with a `TemplateNumberFormat`, but they might as well modified FreeMarker... AFAK they have their own closed source branch.

Comment: `${1}` does not have a `R`. `${item.rate?string('#.00')}` loses the R as well, and also `${item.rate + 1}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Freemarker `?has_content` function can give unexpected results - especially when you don't control the underlying data model (which is the case with NetSuite).  Essentially what's happening is that the `item.rate` being passed is not `null` and does not meet `?has_content`'s definition of "empty", even though it looks empty.  You can use `?length gt 0` instead:

```
  <td align="right" colspan="4"><#if item.rate?length gt 0>${item.rate?keep_before_last(".")}.${item.rate?keep_after_last(".")[0..1]}<#else>&nbsp;</#if></td>
```

This would still be a problem if, for example, an `item.rate` was for some reason passed to the template with no ".", as it would still end up with an empty string, for which the `[0..1]` index would be invalid.

So, you could test whether the `item.rate` `?contains` the decimal separator instead:

```
<td align="right" colspan="4"><#if item.rate?contains(".")>${item.rate?keep_before_last(".")}.${item.rate?keep_after_last(".")[0..1]}<#else>&nbsp;</#if></td>
```

But the simplest thing to do might be to use Freemarker's built in currency string formatting instead:

```
<td align="right" colspan="4">${item.rate?string.currency}</td>
```

Comment: Thanks! `<td align="right" colspan="4"><#if item.rate?contains(".")>${item.rate?keep_before_last(".")}.${item.rate?keep_after_last(".")[0..1]}<#else>${item.rate}</#if></td>` did the trick. Using `string.currency` for some reason returns `$` instead of `R`.

Comment: The output of `?string.currency` depends on the locale settings that Freemarker is being run with.  This should be set in NetSuite at Setup>Company>Company Information>Currency Locale.  Alternatively, you can override the locale setting inside the template thus: `<#setting locale="en_ZA"><td align="right" colspan="3">${item.rate?string.currency}</td>`.

Comment: You can avoid the `#if`-s, and just use a single expression: `${item.rate?replace(r'(\d\.\d{2})\d+', '$1', 'r')}`. Now of course it's still ugly enough to put it into a `#function` with descriptive name... (Or frankly, it would be best if Netsuite guys show up on the FM mailing list if they need a feature to handle these annotated numbers properly, like so that ?string('0.00') will work with them...)

Answer (score 1):

Since you said rate null  You can use the ?? test operator:

```
<#if item.rate??></#if>
```

Also if you want to check multiple condition you can check `<#if item.rate?? &&  item.rate?has_content></#if>`

For money format you can refer this link [docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_depr_numerical_interpolation.html#autoid_136) . If you want custom format you can do try [this](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_custom_formats.html)

```
${item.rate:M2}
```

Comment: That means `item` itself null then

Comment: `item` is not null, it prints values in the other columns. `item.rate` however is null

Comment: I think instead of round trip you can use `item.rate?string.currency`. You can replace that line

Comment: As stated in my text I did not have any success with `item.rate?string.currency` since it looses the currency symbol.

Comment: Just add your expected output for the column. i will try to resolve it other way. it seems like we doing wrong way.

Comment: `item.rate` is normally something like `R123.45678` but I would like to print `R123.45` or `R123.46`. `R` is for the currency symbol for the currency `ZAR`. If I use `string.currency` it prints something similar to `#`. Sometimes `item.rate` can be null though.